# python как заполнить данными List с вложенными словарями

Tags: python, циклы, list, словари

Как можно сформировать список с вложенной структурой используя цикл или иной способ используя новые значения из tableWidget. И таким образом получить новый набор данных с такой же структурой как у примера ниже !

Есть такой набор данных:

```
trade_levels = [
            {"Id": "EURUSD", "Level1": 1.19507, "Level2": 1.18701, "Level3": 1.20012},
            {"Id": "GBPUSD", "Level1": 1.2000, "Level2": 2.010, "Level3": 1.60}
               ]

trade_levels_new = []                      # формиование нового list значениями из tableWidget
        for i in range(2):                       # цикл по строкам из range(3)
            a = self.tableWidget.item(1, i)      # пробегаем по tableWidget считываем новые значения
            value = a.text()                             # value from tableWidget
            trade_levels_new.append(value)  # ??? как создать новый список подобно trade_levels
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте пример списка, который должен получиться.

Comment: А что за набор слов в вопросе? Вы сами перечитывали то, что написали? Пунктуацией умеете пользоваться?

Comment: Сорри шас подправлю спешил видимо последствия вакцинации только сделали :)